# Sort bidimensionnal double array java

Tags: java, arrays, double

I'm having some troubles sorting my dynamic bidimensionnal array.
I searched and found this solution :

```
Double[][] sortedOutput = new Double[length][4];

//... 
// processing and filling my tab like that
sortedOutput[k][0] = content[i].getLeftSpeed);
sortedOutput[k][1] = content[i].getRightSpeed();
sortedOutput[k][2] = content[i].getNormAvgPowOutput();

// ... 
// Now i'm trying to sort the tab
Arrays.sort(sortedOutput, new java.util.Comparator<double[]>()
{
  public int compare(double[]a, double[]b)
  {
    return Double.compare(a[0], b[0]);
  }
});
```

But somehow i doesn't work :

```
The method sort(T[], Comparator<? super T>) in the type Arrays is not applicable for the arguments (Double[][], new Comparator<double[]>(){})
```

Why can't i use `Arrays.sort` with `double` ?

I also tried to make a class :

```
package IOControl;

import java.util.Comparator;

public class CompareDoubleArray implements Comparator<double[]>
{
     private int column;

     public CompareDoubleArray(int column)
     {
        this.column = column;
     }

     public int compare(double[] arg0, double[] arg1) 
     {
        return Double.valueOf(arg0[column]).compareTo(Double.valueOf(arg1[column]));
     }
 }
```

How should i use my class ? What did i do wrong?
Any help would be nice, thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to type your `Comparator` on `Double[]`. A `double[]` is not the same thing as `Double[]`. One is an array of primitives the other is an array of `Double` objects which are wrappers for primitives.

```
Arrays.sort(sortedOutput, new java.util.Comparator<Double[]>()
{
  public int compare(Double[]a, Double[]b)
  {
    return Double.compare(a[0], b[0]);
  }
});
```

Comment: Okey i tried this, but now i'm still having this issue : 
`java.lang.NullPointerException
 at IOControl.ReadCSV$1.compare(ReadCSV.java:326)
 at IOControl.ReadCSV$1.compare(ReadCSV.java:1)
 at java.util.TimSort.countRunAndMakeAscending(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.TimSort.sort(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.TimSort.sort(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Arrays.sort(Unknown Source)
 at IOControl.ReadCSV.run(ReadCSV.java:322)
 at en.window.Main.main(Main.java:46)`

Comment: @trolologuy Check that your `sortedOutput` array is correctly populated. Namely check that `sortedOutput[i][0]` is **not null** for all `i`. Sounds like one might be null and then you get a `NullPointerException` during unboxing while calling `Double.compare`

Comment: Okey you are right, some are `null`... but i don't understand why, so i tried to assign the `null` values to 0.0.
But i can't because `The operator == is undefined for the argument type(s) double, null`.
How can i fix that?

Comment: @trolologuy I'm not sure I quite understand how you changed the code. Might be worth it to ask as a new SO question with the updated code? Doesn't seem to be related to sorting the array anymore, but rather to how it is initialized.

Comment: yeah you are right, i think you answered my question brillantly.
I asked my question in a more specific way here : [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18763990/filling-an-bidimensionnal-array-in-java) .
I will accept your Question, if i finally find a solution to my problem.
Thanks for your help !

Comment: Yup, thanks everything is solved by chance (answer on the other post).

Answer (score 0):

[Arrays.sort](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort) takes only `single dimensional array` as argument.So you can't use `multidimensional array`here

Try this code may help you.

```
for(Double[] d : sortedOutput){
   Arrays.sort(d , new Comparator<Double>(){
         @Override
         public int compare(Double o1, Double o2) {

        //implement logic here
         }
   });
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but what do you mean exactly by `//implement logic here` ?
What am i supposed to do now? Same as before?

Comment: @trologuy yes same as before