# filling an bidimensionnal array in java

Tags: java, arrays, nullpointerexception

I'm having some issues filling a bidimensionnal double-array out of a multi-dimensional object-array.
My problem is that null value are causing a `java.lang.NullPointerException
    at IOControl.ReadCSV$1.compare(ReadCSV.java:328)
    at IOControl.ReadCSV$1.compare(ReadCSV.java:1)
    at java.util.TimSort.countRunAndMakeAscending(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.TimSort.sort(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.TimSort.sort(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Arrays.sort(Unknown Source)
    at IOControl.ReadCSV.run(ReadCSV.java:324)
    at en.window.Main.main(Main.java:46)` , and i really don't understand why.

**What am i doing ?** 
I'm reading a CSV - file, i'm storing the input line by line, in my array of object `Data` called `content`.
Then i'm filling a `double` bidimensional array called `sortedOutput` in which i would like to store `LeftSpeed` and `NormAvgPowOutput` which are double value stored in my `Data` array.

**What i want :**
To have my `sortedOutput` bidimensionnal array sorted from the smallest to the biggest value on dimension 0 : for variable `LeftSpeed`.

So how can i avoid the null values? Because when i try to spot them while filling my second array, the compilator says i can't compare a double to a `null` value.

Sorry for the long post, hope you guys can help me out :)
Here my code :

```
public void run(String path, int length) 
{
/* 
* Main function of ReadCSV class.
 * Open / reads / closes the file.
 * Fills the object.
 */

  BufferedReader br = null;
  String input = "";
  String cvsSplitBy = ",";
  int[] pos = new int[200];

  Data[] content = new Data[length];
  Double[][] sortedOutput = new Double[length][4];
  int i = 0;
  int j = 0;
  int k = 0;

  try 
  {
    br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
    while ((input = br.readLine()) != null) 
     {
       // use comma as separator
       String[] lines = input.split(cvsSplitBy);
       content[i] = new Data(); 
       if (i == 0)
       {
         //not relevant here                
       }
       else
       {
        j = 0;
        content[i].setTime("TIME", getTime(pos[j++], lines));
        content[i].setData("DATA", getContent(pos[j++], lines));
        //etc
       }
       // gets rid of non coherent or useless values, e.g negative power, ...
       if (content[i].lhWdStdev > 0 && content[i].rhWdStdev > 0)
       {
        normalizeData(content[i]); // not relevant
        content[k].setLeftSpeed();
        sortedOutput[k][0] = content[k].getLeftSpeed();
        sortedOutput[k][2] = content[k].getNormAvgPowOutput();
        Arrays.sort(sortedOutput, new java.util.Comparator<Double[]>()
        {
           public int compare(Double[]a, Double[]b)
           {
             return Double.compare(a[0], b[0]);
            }
         });
   }
   if (sortedOutput[k][0] == null)
   {
     System.out.println("FAIL");
   }
   System.out.println("Output = " +sortedOutput[k][0]);
   i++;
   k++;
 }
} 
catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
  {
    e.printStackTrace();
  } 
catch (IOException e) 
  {
    e.printStackTrace();
  } 
finally 
  {
  // Again it's not relevant
}
```

EDIT : So finally i made 2 huge misstakes.
First i tried to sort the array in the loop, that means BEFORE it was fully filled (thanks @Ted Hopp).
Secondly i didn't handle the `null` values correctly. I should have checked if (`a != null`, `b != null`, `a[0] != null`, `b[0] != null` ) and then return the new order. (thanks @jboi ).

Comment: Which line is throwing the NPE?

Comment: You really need to post the FULL stacktrace if you want helpful comments.

Comment: Is there a reason why you implement it yourself? There are good open source libraries to do CSV parsing. Like http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/

Comment: The problematic line is when i start trying to start my array :
`        Arrays.sort(sortedOutput, new java.util.Comparator<Double[]>()` .
And this because one of the values is obviously `null` but i don't know how to avoid this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I see from the stacktace is, that the command `Double.compare(a[0], b[0]);` is causing the NullPointerException. That means, that one the two is `null`. What you can to as a quick solution is to change the command with:

```
Double.compare((a[0]==null)? Double.NaN:a[0], (b[0]==null)? Double.NaN:b[0]);
```

This can only be quick and dirty as you need to understand WHY there're null, what is in the CSV File, that makes them null and how you handle such data.

Comment: My csv-file is composed by data put together by captors, and sometimes the values can be `null` (if there is an error, ...), therefore i can simply ignore those results, because i need to draw a curve out of the csv file.

I did'nt thought the check could be done as easily ! Thanks :)

Comment: After the loop, when i try to read my tab as follow `    k = 0;
while (sortedOutput[k] != null)
{
     System.out.println("Speed = " +sortedOutput[k][0]);
System.out.println("Power = " +sortedOutput[k][2]);
k++;
}
` but when i display my values during the loop in which i fill the tab, those values aren't `null`.

Comment: Strange. There's something wrong, that is not in the code or it so obvious, I don't see it. Could you check in the `comparator`, directly before the `return Double.compare...` and check for one of the following conditions: `a == null, b == null, a[0] == null, b[0] == null`

Comment: @jboy Nothing changed so far, maybe it's just my display.
I'll try to solve this.

Comment: @jboy, okey got this one fixed, my display was wrong.
Now the values are ordered correctly :D
Everything works nearly perfectly.
You sir, desserve a cookie (and the others too) :D Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

You are crashing because you are sorting the array `sortedOutput` before you have read all the entries. The call to `Arrays.sort()` should be moved to past the loop where you are reading the input.

Alternatively, you can call `Arrays.sort()` with an expanded argument list to control how much of the array is sorted:

```
Arrays.sort(sortedOutput, 0, k + 1, new java.util.Comparator<Double[]>()
    {
       public int compare(Double[]a, Double[]b)
       {
         return Double.compare(a[0], b[0]);
        }
     });
```

However, I see no reason to constantly be sorting after each input.

You also oddly have the check against array elements being `null` coming after the call to `Arrays.sort()` which requires them to not be `null`. If you use the second option, you at least need to move the error checks to before the sort.

As a third alternative, you could explicitly allow for a `null` array entry inside your comparator. All `null` entries should sort the same and should always be either before or after non-`null` entries.

Comment: That's true :o
You are right on that, still crashing, but i think @autra completes your answer.

Comment: @trolologuy - If it still crashes after you move the call to after the loop, then somehow you are still allowing `null` entries despite the check.

Comment: @trolologuy - Inside the comparator, it would simply be `if (a[0] == null)`, etc. You might consider exiting your `run()` method immediately if you print `FAIL` during the `null` check.

Answer (score 0):

So first of all, finally clause is relevant here : you need to invoke the close() method of your stream br there, to avoid any resource leak in case of exceptions.

Secondly, I see no advantage of using arrays instead of list here. In java, we use lists (especially ArrayList in this case) over arrays. Arrays are seldom used, not like in C. Perfs are quite the same (providing you init your list with the same size as you do with your array). Lists are better, because they give you better compile-time check, whereas Arrays only gives runtime-check.
For example, the following code compiles without errors:

```
String[] strings = new String[1];
Object[] objects = strings;
objects[0] = new Integer(1);
```

Thirdly, when you have an exception, it is critical that you post here the FULL stacktrace. People will give you better help if they have better information!

Fortunately, here, I can see where the NPE is thrown: Double.compare takes two double as arguments (and not Double). Therefore, your Double are autoboxed to double (google "java autoboxing"), throwing a NPE if they are null. You need to handle the 3 cases of nullity (one is null, the other, and both of them) in your comparator. Alternatively, you can remove null values before sorting.

Comment: First : I didn't wanted to post my full code, because it would have been way to long, but in my version, i do close the file ;)

Secondly : I needed 3 different types stored in my Array (with many columns), that's why i thought an object-array would be easier.

Thirdly : I edited my post (sorry for that).

Thanks for you answer, i'll try to understand autoboxing and correct my misstake.
I would like to remove the null values, but i don't know how, because when i'm trying to see if the value is null, the compilator says that ican't compare a double with null.Maybe you have another clue on that?